# How to get valu of object in php?

Tags: php, html

i have a problem when i try to get the object value there's nothing in it. but when i just echo the object , there's no null i dont know how to get that value

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $secret = "6Le3nvgUAAAAAMU0DRNLtvtaIq3h6X9ybEnO_txv";
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret='.$secret.'&response='.$captcha;

    $response = file_get_contents($url);


    echo $response;


}
```

i got response

[image]

but when i try to $response-> success . it return null ..

Comment: Please learn how to properly parse JSON, you cannot expect PHP to magically interpret any random string by just simply calling something on it.

Comment: i jsut know that the object is from JSON. tyy

Answer (score 0):

The response you 've got is written in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON). For this purpose PHP got it 's own JSON [decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and [encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) functions.

```
$decodedResponse = json_decode($response);
var_dump($decodedResponse->success);
```

Comment: wow great tyy . but the value now bool(true) , how to compare to $response == true ? 1 :  0 .

Comment: You should definitely learn some PHP basics. Here you go: [If-conditions with PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/de/control-structures.if.php) and [how to dump the content of variables](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.var-dump). I bet you 'll find out by yourself.

Comment: i already find out bro. thanks